# Select case with different queries

Tags: select, stored-procedures, case, case-when

in my current project I use a lot of stored procedures. In order to reduce the number of SPs I am thinking of putting several queries in one SQ, i. E.

```
enter code here@ArtQuery int = 0
    /*      
    0 = SELECT
    1 = INSERT
    2 = UPDATE
    3 = DELETE
    */
enter code hereAS   
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT 
    CASE
WHEN @ArtQuery = 0
--Select Statement
WHEN @ArtQuery = 1
--Insert Statement
```

Unfortunately that does not work. The select statement is accepted, the others aren't. Is that my mistake or isn't it possible having different queries in one SP?

Comment: looks like you want a `IF` statement refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Please tag this SQL

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using IF clauses instead.